# How to see a history of index reorganization requests for a specific index in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing, reorganize

In SQL Server 2008, when trying to reorganize an index on a table, I see this error:

*The index "MyIndex" (partition 1) on table "MyTable" cannot be reorganized because it is being reorganized by another process*

I see the error message returned as part of an SSIS package failure. This happened after hours when I was not around to quickly look at something like Activity Monitor to indentify the culprit process.

My question is how to identify this other reorganization process a day after the fact?

Ideally, I would like to see a history of index reorganization requests for a specific index

Comment: By default, SQL Server doesn't log individual operations like this anywhere. Perhaps you can look at `sys.dm_exec_requests` and `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` to see if one is *currently* running before trying to start another. You could also use a trace or extended events session to log these manually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not something that SQL Server 2008 does by default and I do not have anything built out that would specifically capture these events so I am out of luck.